# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Coordinator in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting an error message that says the following:

> Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Coordinator'

The debugger runs and breaks on `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);`.
I am currently using Visual Studio 16.3.0 Preview 3, because I was having issue with current release versions, in this preview there is Xamarin android bug fixes.

When I remove `<include layout="@layout/include_main"/>` from activity_main.axml, I then get an error that says

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

on `SupportActionBar.Title = "";` in MainActivity.cs.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase;
using Android.Views;

namespace PaleteroGo
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/PaleteroTheme", MainLauncher = false)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        FirebaseDatabase database;
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar mainToolbar;
        Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main); //debugger breaks here
            ConnectControl();
        }

        void ConnectControl()
        {
            drawerLayout = (Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.drawerLayout);
            mainToolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.mainToolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = ""; //then breaks here
            Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBar actionBar = SupportActionBar;
            actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Mipmap.ic_help_action);
            actionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    drawerLayout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }
        }

        void Initializedatabase()
        {
            ...
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >

        <include
        layout="@layout/include_main"

        />

        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:background="@color/paleteroWhite"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerlayout"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**include_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.Coordinator 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/paleteroAsh"
        >   

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        />

        </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.Coordinator>
```

Comment: could you show your `include_main` xaml,does it contain toolbar?.if not,you could change like below,and chek it

Comment: Yes it does have toolbar implemented. Posted code.

Comment: I also removed the toolbar xml code, but still had same error message.

Comment: have you try the below codes ? remove the toolbar from include_main xaml

Comment: Yes thats what I meant, I removed the toolbar from include_main and tried your code, but the same error.

Comment: you try to use the include_main xaml below,it works on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:minWidth="25dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:id="@+id/mainToolbar" />
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
       android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
       layout="@layout/include_main"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/nav_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       app:headerLayout="@layout/headerlayout"
       app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
    />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**include_main** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I decided I wanted to change `actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Mipmap.ic_help_action);` to `actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Mipmap.ic_menu_action);` and I added the ic_menu_action.png icons to the mipmap folders and now get similar error message. `Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

09-27 20:23:31.229 W/roGo.PaleteroG( 5103): Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk
09-27 20:23:31.229 W/roGo.PaleteroG( 5103): Could not merge the profile. Clearing the profile data.` Also using visual studio 2017 in this case.

Comment: Should I have been using the latest preview version instead? I was waiting for the update to finish.

Comment: Nevermind, I can confirm it is working fine when updated to visual studio 16.4.0 preview 1.

Comment: It looks like it keeps coming back and forth.
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Coordinator
...

Comment: And also Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.Coordinator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/PaleteroGo.PaleteroGo-OVejOH8Y-YE04grCXVNgBQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/PaleteroGo.PaleteroGo-OVejOH8Y-YE04grCXVNgBQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/PaleteroGo.PaleteroGo-OVejOH8Y-YE04grCXVNgBQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with library? I cannot get a preview when changing xml, get message "Could not load controls from the Android Support Library. Performing a Nuget restore may fix this."